# Admob in TabHost is active one time

Tags: android, admob

I make app with TabHost. On 3th tab I placed admob. Its still on test mode, but its working properly until I change tab. When I click tab2 or 1 and I want go back to admob ad on tab3 , tab3 is empty. What can I do to load ad when tab3 is active?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for wasting your time. On real device admob works properly. In AVD add was showed only once. On my mobile (api 23) add is on tab3 all the time.